# F# PostgreSQL connection with SQLprovider failing without error in project but intellisense indicates code is fine and works in interactive

Tags: postgresql, f#, type-providers

I am connecting to a local PostgreSQL db using SQLprovider in F#. The code works in interactive and intellisense is detecting the tables in the database fine, but the compiled project breaks when it runs the sql.GetDataContext() line without any error. I find it strange that the exact same code runs in interactive, that the connection must be working as intellisense on "ctx" below is picking up the tables, and I cannot see what is wrong. New to F# and databases and can't see why this does not work, any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```ml
type sql = SqlDataProvider<DatabaseVendor=Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL,ConnectionString="Server=localhost;Database=DB1;User Id=postgres;Password=pw1",ResolutionPath=@"path for npgsql.dll">

type saver(datatype:string, handle:string) =   
        member __.DataType = datatype
        member __.Handle = handle   
        member __.save() =  
            let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
            /// rest of code, not causing any issues
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say the compiled project breaks? You must be getting some sort of error or stacktrace, no? Are both the compiled project and the db 64-bit/32-bit? What happens if you define ctx outside of your type and pass it in?

Comment: Its actually part of a larger project which is an excel addin with excel-dna, when running in debug it runs up to any type or module with the "sql.GetDataContext()" in it and breaks out. Both the db and project are 64 bit, and I have tried defining ctx outside and passing in, same result

Comment: that's an interesting combo. I wonder if the type provider works inside the excel add-in. Is that native code? Maybe you can try something simple with the CSV type provider and see if it works?

Comment: seems the compiled code runs fine on another machine and can read and write to the db from excel (both are 64 bit windows 10 with same VS/postgres/excel versions)with exactly the same local database setup as far as i can see, infuriating and time wasting. i still cant see why it would run in interactive and intellisense sees the db tables in visual studio on both machines but the compiled only works on one, if there's anything obvious to look for would be appreciated (especially if anyone has seen a similar issue before with SqlDataProvider), otherwise probably not worth wasting anyone's time!